# IE 7 and Website Rendering Problems

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I am not sure what is wrong with the following page and all the article pages on this website. The page is not even displayed completely.

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/717_Populating_TreeView_with_Different_Sources.aspx

On FireFox, Chrome and IE 8 it works fine.

IE 7 has problems! Now what should I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a page renders successfully, it is either because your page has no errors or because the browser was able to cope with them.

If a page doesn't render successfully, it is either because your page has errors, because the browser has bugs, or a combination of the two.

The first thing to do is eliminate all the bugs you can find.

[The markup has 107 errors (at the time of writing).](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhighoncoding.com%2FArticles%2F717_Populating_TreeView_with_Different_Sources.aspx&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Once those are eliminated you can move onto [checking the CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Holy COW!!! I guess IE7 cannot perform well with all those errors. I will check the errors out. 107 is waaay too many!

Comment: For some reason these errors don't show up in VS 2008 even with the XHTML validation enabled.